# Падеж в словосочетании

Tags: грамотная-речь, падежи, управление

По ТВ ведущий сказал(передача "Чудо техники"):
**Новость недели, *заслужившая первого места...***

Может, нужно "первое место"? Как правильно?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно: первое место. Глагол "заслужить" требует винительного падежа.

Заслужить что **(не чего).** Заслужить награду. Заслужить любовь коллектива... Они вполне заслужили свое положение и счастье (Каверин).

Пунктуация и управление в русском языке Д.Э. Розенталь.

Answer (score 1):

Там контекст нужен. На фейсбуке его не нашел, хотя гугл дает ссылку. 
Норма может меняться по разным причинам, под действием, например, формы управления других глаголов: "добившаяся первого места". И надо смотреть на логическую определенность конструкции.

Как анонс "А сейчас новость, заслужившая первого места" неприемлемо,
надо сказать "заслуживающая" - тогда родительный уместен.

Но "Новость, заслужившая первого места, оказалась совсем не на первом" - это нормально.

Comment: Я в целом согласен, только одного не понял, при чем тут вид глагола или причастия?

Comment: Ой, а правда. Р. так и пишет. "Заслуживать чего, заслужить что". Но тогда объясните, почему вы считаете, что норма изменилась.

Comment: В вашем последнем примере "заслужившая" с родительным падежом не проходит - возможно _заслуживавшая_ (мнение о новости в ситуации, когда место не было занято). Здесь всё решает реалистичность ситуации, создаваемой вариантом глагола ("заслужившая" синонимично "занявшей" и совпадает по управлению с этим причастием, образованным от переходного глагола).

Comment: Хотел ссылку дать, не разрешил модератор, а в комменты не лезет. Посмотрите в гуглокнигах на текст от Сержа.

Comment: Позволю себе дерзновение и дам всё-таки ту ссылку, о которой говорит  @Мимоходов: https://goo.gl/7KDzLV. А то я прям тиран — прошу правила сайта соблюдать!

Comment: @ Aer, а эту ссылку в ответе дать нельзя?

Comment: @Миомоходов, спасибо, но я понял о чем вы, не связываетесь с "тираном". Там нет объяснения, как зависит падеж дополнения от вида глагола. А это противоречит одному из основополагающих правил русской грамматики. Можно отдельным вопросом обсудить.